# To find the initial value problem $y(x) = 1 + \int_{0}^x (t-x) y(t)\,dt$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The initial value problem corresponding to the integral equation

$$y(x) = 1 + \int_{0}^x (t-x) y(t)\,dt$$ is?

Comment: what do you mean by $\int_{i=0}(t-x)y(t)dt$ ? is it simply $\int_0^t (t-x)y(t)dt$ ?

Comment: Your lower bound of the integral makes no sense. What is i? You need to apply the leibniz rule for differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: Sorry,it was my mistake, the limit of Integral is from 0 to x. I've edited the question.

Comment: @thespoiledboy Do you have any thoughts?  Can you at least see what is a natural choice for the initial position $x_0$, and what the value of $y(x_0)$ is?  Have you tried finding a formula for $y'$?  What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite the integral equation as

$$y(x) = 1 + \int_0^x t\cdot y(t) \, dt -x \cdot \int_0^x y(t) \, dt$$

By inspection we have $y(0)=1$. Now, differentiation with respect to $x$ yields (by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and product rule):

\begin{aligned}y'(x)&=x\cdot y(x)-\int_0^xy(t)\,dt-x\cdot y(x)\\
&=-\int_0^xy(t)\,dt\end{aligned}

Once again by inspection, we have that $y'(0)=0$. One last differentiation yields:

$$y''(x)=-y(x)$$

so that your initial value problem can be stated as:

\begin{equation}
\left \{ \begin{array}{l}
y(0)=1\\
y'(0)=0\\
y''(x)=-y(x)\end{array} \right. \end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Take Laplace transforms.  Define

$$Y(s) = \int_0^{\infty} dt \, y(t) e^{-s t}$$

Then the integral equation is equivalent to, by the convolution theorem,

$$Y(s) = \frac1s - \frac1{s^2} Y(s) \implies s^2 Y(s) + Y(s) - s = 0$$

Note that the diff eq'n $a y''+b y'+c y=0$, $y(0)=y_0$, $y'(0)=y'_0$ has Laplace transform

$$(a s^2+b s+c)Y(s) -a y'_0 - (a s+b)y_0 = 0$$

Equating coefficients (i.e., $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=1$), we find that $y_0=1$ and $y'_0=0$.  Thus, the IVP is

$$y''+y=0$$
$$y(0) = 1$$
$$y'(0)=0$$